# Qt C++ lambda expression does not deduce return type

Tags: c++, qt, lambda

I have a lambda expression, which wraps a member function from another class so I can use it in other classes like it's their own member.

```
auto fun = [this] (const QString& imageName) -> QImage {
    typedef QImage result_type;
    return _mapper(imageName);
};
```

The *_mapper* functor is from another class and returns a `QImage`.

Now my problem is that either the compiler or the Qt function, which I'm using it in, doesn't like this and can't deduce the result type.

```
QtConcurrent/qtconcurrentmapkernel.h:124: error: no type named ‘result_type’ in ‘struct *mystruct_ptr*::<lambda(const class QString&)>’
     IntermediateResults<typename MapFunctor::result_type> results;
                                                           ^
```

But a more traditional `std::bind` works:

```
auto fun_binded = std::bind(&Mapper::operator(), &_mapper, std::placeholders::_1);
```

So the **question**: What's the problem with the lambda?

Maybe I should mention the context in which I am using it:

```
QtConcurrent::mappedReduced<QList<QImage>>(*image_container*, fun, fun_reduce))
```

`fun_reduce` was done similarly, except it has a `void` function.

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that a lambda does not define the member type `result_type` that the library uses in `typename MapFunctor::result_type` but `std::function` does.

The library expects `result_type` to be defined.

So either stick to `std::bind`, or wrap your lambda in an std::function:

```
// This will convert the lambda to an std::function
std::function<QImage(const QString&)> fun =
     [this](const QString& imageName) { return _mapper(imageName);};
```

Or write a custom struct with this type defined.

```
struct MyFunctor
{
    using result_type = QImage;

    // Here you must store a pointer or a ref to the "owner" (this)

    QImage operator()(const QString& imageName) {
        return owner->mapper(imageName);
    }
};
```

Comment: "So just define" -- I think the error message is saying the use comes from a header file that the OP shouldn't be modifying.

Comment: @hvd you are probably right. I have no idea where to define the `result_type` or why is that the `QtConcurrent::mappedReduced` works with the `std::function` and the `void` lambda, but not with this.

Comment: @hvd You are right, I didn't notice it was a thirdparty issue. Just looked at it and fixed my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::function` but it has unnecessary overhead. I suggest to use the wrapper:

```
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtConcurrent/QtConcurrent>

#include <type_traits>

struct Item
{
    QDateTime timestamp;
    QByteArray json;
};

template< typename Result, typename Functor >
struct FunctorWithResultTypedef
        : std::decay_t< Functor >
{

    using result_type = Result;

    FunctorWithResultTypedef(Functor & functor)
        : std::decay_t< Functor >{std::forward< Functor >(functor)}
    { ; }

};

template< typename Result, typename Functor >
FunctorWithResultTypedef< Result, Functor >
addResultTypedef(Functor && functor)
{
    return {functor};
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    QDir jsonDir{R"(input/)"};
    auto pattern = QStringLiteral("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH'%1'mm'%1'ss'.'zzz").arg(QChar(0xF03A));
    auto fileInfos = jsonDir.entryInfoList(QStringList{} << "*.json", (QDir::Readable | QDir::Files));
    auto map = [&pattern] (const QFileInfo & fileInfo) -> Item
    {
        auto dateTime = QDateTime::fromString(fileInfo.completeBaseName().chopped(3), pattern);
        Q_ASSERT(dateTime.isValid());
        QFile file{fileInfo.filePath()};
        if (!file.open(QFile::ReadOnly)) {
            qFatal("unable to open file %s to read", qPrintable(file.fileName()));
        }
        QJsonParseError jsonParseError;
        auto jsonDocument = QJsonDocument::fromJson(file.readAll(), &jsonParseError);
        if (jsonDocument.isNull()) {
            qFatal("wrong JSON: %1", qPrintable(jsonParseError.errorString()));
        }
        return {dateTime, jsonDocument.toJson(QJsonDocument::Indented)};
    };
    using ResultType = QByteArray;
    auto reduce = [] (ResultType & json, const Item & item)
    {
        json.append(item.json);
    };
    auto result = QtConcurrent::blockingMappedReduced< ResultType >(fileInfos, addResultTypedef< Item >(map), addResultTypedef< ResultType >(reduce), QtConcurrent::SequentialReduce);
    {
        QFile file{R"(output.json)"};
        if (!file.open(QFile::Truncate | QFile::WriteOnly)) {
            qFatal("unable to open file %s to write", qPrintable(file.fileName()));
        }
        file.write(result);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```